# How to handle form.submit() in JavaScript with Spring WebFlow

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

How to handle form.submit() in JavaScript with Spring WebFlow

I am know to web flow and the project I am working on it using javascript to check all the fields before submitting data to the server.

Example:

```
<INPUT tabIndex="46" value="Submit" type="button" name="_eventId_submit" OnClick="return checkrequired();">
```

Here is the javascript

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function checkrequired()
{
.....
form.submit();
return true;
}
```

but it looks like webflow does not help the submit.. can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to update your HTML like this....
<pre><code>
<form action="" onsubmit="return checkrequired">
....
<INPUT tabIndex="46" value="Submit" type="submit" name="_eventId_submit">
</form>
function checkrequired()
{
.....
//form.submit(); remove this
return true;
}
</code></pre>
```

Comment: if the javascript finds errors, return false, this will stop the form from submitting.

Comment: Best practice is, you can put your code in "try-catch" block, if you want to post the form "return true", other wise "return false".